# FireBase rule newData with uid

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

How can i to use unique id of new data in rule with newData?

Data structure:
[image]

I want to disallow to write for the users which one senderName is in ban_users, but i cannot to get the newData senderName:

```
newData('senderName').val(); //not working
newData('$message_id/senderName').val(); //also not working("$message_id": {})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disallow writes to `messages/main/$id`, try the following write rule:

`!root.child('chat/ban_users').hasChild(newData.child('senderName').val())`

Comment: o thank U, I wrote $message_id in room child
Thank U very much